# Get Date From Filename Using ParseExact

Tags: c#, string

I am trying to find the file that has the highest date in a single directory.  The problem is that the dates are attached to filenames.  I am using the following code to try to pull the max date but am running into trouble with the ParseExact.

```
//Gather all of the files in the local directory
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(r.getLeadLocalFile());
returnDateTime = files.Max(f => DateTime.ParseExact(f, "MMddyyXXXX.csv", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

I continue to get the following error:

```
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

I can tell that the value of the file path is being passed in because the value of 'f' is below:

```
\\\\vamarnas02\\users\\meggleston\\User Files\\Leads\\110716ENH9.csv
```

The value of ENH9 can change depending on the file.

How can I get the DateTime from my filename?

Comment: Do you have some control about how those files are created...can you add an `_` between the date and the name, like `110716_ENH9.csv`?

Comment: Can't you simply substring the first 6 chars from the file name?

Comment: I do not have control of the filename and I am not sure how to get the max datetime with the substring method.

Comment: Still don't think that ParseExact is good choice for finding max date, you will have to recheck that you have EXACTLY the files with your date format and nothing else, or the exception will be thrown. If the format of saving files changes in the future project iterations - you will have to rebuild your code with another format in ParseExact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split out the date text before parsing. The following code snippet should help.

Assume the variable f is the filename.

```
DateTime.ParseExact(f.Substring( f.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1,  6), "MMddyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: That did it.  I think I've been looking at this too long.  Thanks for helping a dummy like myself.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach.  No need to split out anything.  But one bad filename (as with your current approach) will ruin it:

```
//Gather all of the files in the local directory
var files = new DirectoryInfo(r.getLeadLocalFile()).GetFiles("*.csv");
returnDateTime = files.Max(f => DateTime.ParseExact(f.Name.Substring(0, 6), "MMddyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try only passing the filename "110716ENH9.csv" instead of the full path of the file.

From [MSDN DateTime.ParseExact Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its DateTime equivalent using the specified format and culture-specific format information. The format of the string representation must match the specified format exactly.

From what you've provided, your format does not match exactly.

--
Only pass the first 6 characters of the filename to the ParseExact function and amend your format to be "MMddyy."

Comment: I have changed my code to the following but still receiving the same error:  

`returnDateTime = files.Max(f => DateTime.ParseExact(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f), "MMddyyXXXX", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));`

Comment: There are no wildcards in the Date Format.  You'll need to substring the filename.  Since you know the date format only needs the first 6 characters, only pass the first 6 characters of the filename to the ParseExact function and amend your format to be "MMddyy."

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to use ParseExact here? Because it seems that you just need to get Int32 values and compare them afterwards.
So another approach: you can extract your date parts with some regex, from the path provided. For example you can use this one:

```
\\\d{6}  // 2 slashes and 6 digits. I'm not an expert in regex, but seems that this one is enough for your task.
```

And trim the `\\` part afterwards. So something like this in the loop:

```
private string ExtractDateFromFilename(string filename) {
        var m = Regex.Match(filename, @"\\\d{6}");
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.Value))
            return m.Value.Substring(1);
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: I would not use RegEx if performance matters, IndexOf  yields faster execution times

Comment: @user2818985 , sure you're right, Regex is slow on large strings (comparing to string methods), but very flexible in case you need to change some conditions in future or have some complex comparison logic. For small strings and not millions of comparisons it won't be a noticeable difference (sorry without proof sample for this one now, maybe will add some later).